# Rails Paperclip Link Existing S3 Assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I have a Video model with a video attachment (using Paperclip and AWS S3 for storage). When a new video is created/uploaded we're using Zencoder to encode the uploaded video into the various formats that we need. This all happens off site and the new encodings are uploaded by zencoder back into S3.

How would I link these new files as styles/variations of the attachment?

In addition, Zencoder also generates thumbnails for us, so how could I also link those to the model instance?